# Avoid duplicates on MySQL update

Tags: mysql

I have a many-to-many relation table like this

| element_a | element_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

I want to replace element_a with id 2 by id 1

```
UPDATE mytable x
SET x.element_a = 1
WHERE x.element_a = 2;
```

Since there is an unique index on (element_a, element_b ), this will result with duplicates error.

How can I execute my query without MySQL Error 1062 ?

Comment: I can see that you would get a duplicate but that contradicts your requirement to replace id2 with id1 so I'm not sure what you want to happen - do you want to leave 2,3 as is or something else.

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicates? Please show us the result that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an update with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
UPDATE mytable x
LEFT JOIN mytable t ON t.element_b = x.element_b AND 1 = t.element_a
SET x.element_a = 1
WHERE 
   x.element_a = 2 AND t.element_a IS NULL
```

If `t.element_a IS NOT NULL` then pair `element_a, element_b` already exists in your table. Thus adding `t.element_a IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause prevents `UPDATE` in case of duplicates.

**[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63b9f5/1)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks